# Understanding the Argument Principle in Conway.

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hi. I am trying to understand (argument principle in Conway) these issues but there is a sentence that I cannot prove rigorously.
"Since no zero or pole of $f$ lies on $\gamma$ there is a disk $B(a,r)$, for each $a\in \left\{\gamma\right\}$, such that, a branch of $\log f(z)$ can be defined  on $B(a,r)$ (simply select $r$ sufficiently small that $f(z)\neq 0$ or $\infty$ in $B(a,r)$)."

**Question 1**. How proves the above sentence? I don't see this. More precisely. I can't find the continuous function $g:B(a,r)\to\mathbb{C}$ which is the branch of $log f(z)$.

**Question 2**. A branch of $\log f(z)$ on $B(a,r)$ is a continuous function $g:B(a,r)\to \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z)=e^{g(z)}$ for all $g\in B(a,r)$, right?

**Question 3**. If $f$ is meromorphic function on $G$ and define $f:G\to\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$ by setting $f(z)=\infty$  whenever $z$ is a pole of $f$, then $f$ is continuous from $G$ into $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$.

In this case, the metric is $d(z,z'):=\frac{2|z-z'|}{\sqrt{ (1+|z|^2)(1+|z'|^2)}}$ if $z,z'\in\mathbb{C}$ and $d(z,z'):=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+|z|^2} }$ if $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $z'=\infty$, right? Where does this metric come from? is deductible?

Answer (score 3):

**Question 1.** This is a generally useful result which you should remember for the future: Let $D\subseteq\mathbb C$ a domain on which every holomorphic function has an antiderivative (for instance, convex domains, star domains, or most generally, simply connected domains) and let $f(z)\neq0$ for all $z\in D$. Then there exists a holomorphic function $L:D\to\mathbb C$ where $f(z)=\exp(L(z))$. $L$ is called a logarithm of $f$.

*proof:* Since $f$ has no zeros, $\frac{f'}{f}$ (called the logarithmic derivative, since $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz}\operatorname{Log}(f)=\frac{f'}{f}$ if a suitable Logarithm exists) is holomorphic on $D$, so it has an antiderivative $F$ by assumption. We will show that $\exp F$ is equal to $f$ up to a multiplicative constant. Consider the derivative of $\frac{\exp F}{f}$ (this is holomorphic on $D$, sonce $f$ has no zeros). Its derivative is

$$\frac{f\frac{f'}{f}\exp F~-~f'\exp F}{f^2}=\frac{f'\exp F~-~f'\exp F}{f^2}=0,$$

so the function itself is a nonzero constant $c$:

$$\frac{\exp F}{f}=c.$$

Nonzero because $\exp$ is never $0$. Solving for $f$ we get

$$f=\exp(F+\log c),$$

where $\log c$ is *some* logarithm of the number $c$. And thus $F(z)+\log c$ is the function $L$ we were looking for.

**Question 2.** Depends. Some authors define it to be not just continuous, but also holomorphic. But on domains this is equivalent, since a continuous inverse of a holomorphic function whose derivative is never $0$ (like $\exp$) is also holomorphic.

**Question 3.** This is the so-called **chordal metric**, and the formulas are correct. We interpret $\bar{\mathbb C}$ as the [Riemannian sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere), which we can embed into $\mathbb R^3$ as the unit sphere, and then take the Euclidean distance between two points on this sphere. That is, we take two points on the sphere, draw a chord from one point to the other (the chord goes through the interior of the sphere, not along its surface!), and measure its distance. You can convince yourself by plugging in some values: The poles $0$ and $\infty$ should be $2$ apart, since that's the sphere's diameter. You'll find that this is true. The same goes for any two points on opposite sides, like $1,-1$ and $\mathrm i,-\mathrm i$. Similarly, $0,1$ should be $\sqrt2$ apart due to the Pythagorean theorem, which is also true.

You can also derive the metric rigorously via the [stereographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection).